# Spring boot application throws error in environment : org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, serialization

I am working on a spring boot application. While running in my local i do not see any issue.But after deploying to the environment, i can see the below error in the environment:

```
"message": "Cannot deserialize; nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to deserialize payload. Is the byte array a result of corresponding serialization for DefaultDeserializer?; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to deserialize object type; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.org.comapany.service.controllers.response.ValidationResponse",
```

I am not really sure how to fix this. I have tried to follow some threads but no luck. Any help on why this issue might occur will be really helpful.

Here is my ValidationRespose class:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ValidationResponse implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8289954889893052860L;

    @JsonProperty(value = "status")
    private List<Status> statuses;

    private Errors error;

    private String traceId;

}
```

Spring Boot Version: 2.1.8

Comment: Looks like the problem is that `Status` class is not serializable

Comment: Also, make sure that `Errors` can be serialized too

Comment: @RostyslavBarmakov but if that is the case how is it working in my local? Any idea on this please?

Comment: And Also Status and Error are both implementing Serializable  @RostyslavBarmakov

Comment: It's kind of common phrase to DevOps 'It works on my local machine' :) But it is hard to define reasons without comparing environments. It may be caused by different java versions, build scripts, etc. Also, it might be caused by different `serialVersionUID`  on client and server apps

Comment: Is your code deployed properly in a higher environment? "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.org.comapany.service.controllers.response.ValidationResponse". and please try building and redeploying your code.

If not please paste the complete code and you may get some useful answers.